# What's the difference using requests.get and requests_session.get?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I saw people sometimes using

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

and sometimes

```
s = requests.session()
s.get(url)
```

Is there any difference or consequence in these two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for [requests.sessions](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L3) you see:

```
"""
requests.session
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This module provides a Session object to manage and persist settings across
requests (cookies, auth, proxies).
"""
```

So if you want to persist cookies etc.. using a session will do that where just using .get does not, the [function](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L686) itself is simply:

```
def session():
    """Returns a :class:`Session` for context-management."""

    return Session()
```

There is no real difference using either approach for a single get but if you want to persist you would use a Session.